# Magento 2 - The linked products data is invalid. Verify the data and try again. (when related product assigned)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I am using Magento 2.3.4 and when I try to relate a product I get the message: `"The linked products data is invalid. Verify the data and try again."`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I have noticed that when updating some products via API i can get this error thrown back. Does not happen to same product when saving within admin

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** Take Database backup before applying this solution.

Check the below tables in your Database:

```
1. catalog_product_link_attribute
2. catalog_product_link_type
```

If these tables are empty, you have to run the below SQL queries in your Database:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute` (`product_link_attribute_id`, `link_type_id`, `product_link_attribute_code`, `data_type`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'position', 'int'),
(2, 4, 'position', 'int'),
(3, 5, 'position', 'int'),
(4, 3, 'position', 'int'),
(5, 3, 'qty', 'decimal');

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link_type` (`link_type_id`, `code`) VALUES
(1, 'relation'),
(3, 'super'),
(4, 'up_sell'),
(5, 'cross_sell');
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: these tables are not empty. I have already these data